# Where is the Node Editor in Blender 2.8?

Tags: node-editor, add-on

I can't seem to find the place, in Blender 2.8, where node-based addons lived in previous versions of Blender, such as Animation Nodes and Sverchok. Does anyone one know where that editor went, if it's being taken out for good or if something else is being developed?

Comment: https://blenderartists.org/t/where-is-node-editor-in-the-latest-builds/1117564/3

Comment: Thanks @WhatAMesh but I've already read that forum entry and they're talking about the shader/material node editor, which is not what I'm looking for... I need to develop a node-based addon but, unless I'm mistaken, it can't live in the shader editor because my addon has nothing to do with shaders?

Comment: As soon as you register a nodetree class, a new node editor for that class will be created.. The API will probably still change a bit, but you can check Jacques Lucke's https://github.com/JacquesLucke/everything_nodes_prototype for more info.

Comment: Oh, that's great! Thanks @Secrop, just what I needed to know. :)

Answer (score 6):

That small drop down option next to object and choose the node editor you need such as `Shader Editor`.

Or by hitting `Shift + F3`

As @prubini87 mentioned, if there are no nodes created the area will be empty.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As stated by [@Secrop](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/36180/secrop): "As soon as you register a nodetree class, a new node editor for that class will be created..". I haven't tested it but at this point, since Blender 2.8 is still under development, I hold this to be the answer to my question.